# How to reorder continuous variable in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a geom_point plot that is colored by some continious varibale: for instaance:

```
    library(gapminder)
ggplot(gapminder)+
  geom_point(aes(year,  y=log(gdpPercap),color=pop))
```

[image]

What I want to do is to reorder the way the points are plotted: so the higher `pop` values were plotted last on a plot ( so it will be easier to see them , and the lower `pop` were at the "background". nI wonder if it is possible?

I know how to do it of color was a factor , but not a continuous variable

Comment: Have you considered other alternatives? I think transparency and other geometries can help you

Comment: yeh i did! but i have too many points ( i work on a global scale) at lower values: so it did not help- even when transperancy is at 0.1. I also used a sqrt transformation for color scale and as  well as log transformation to see if i can see them better- but no luck

Comment: What about other geometries?

Comment: you mean shape argument for geom_point?

Comment: Not shapes, but changing geom_point for another geometry, e.g., geom_jitter or even a density for each year

Comment: Arrange your data before you plot it; the last points will be plotted on top.

Comment: arrange order is not preserved in ggplot, no?

Comment: @Jon-m you are right! it does do the job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrange your data before you plot it; the last points will be plotted last (on top).

```
library(gapminder); library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dplyr::arrange(gapminder, pop)) +
  geom_point(aes(year, log(gdpPercap), color=pop), size = 5)
```

[dot sizes increased to make it clearer to see]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Base R option using `order` like this:

```r
library(gapminder)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(gapminder[order(gapminder$pop),])+
  geom_point(aes(x = year, y=log(gdpPercap),color=pop))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>